# 16 drive RAID recommendation on H730P

Tags: raid6

I have a machine with 16 x 12 TB drives on an H730P controller. What would be the recommended RAID-6 configuration? The drives are of the model Toshiba [MG07SCA12TEY](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/storage/product/data-center-enterprise/cloud-scale-capacity/articles/mg07scaxxx.html)

I am considering 2x 8 drive arrays, 1x 16 drive RAID-60 array and 1x 16 drive RAID-6 array. The server will be primarily used for backups and long term storage. How significant will the impact on going from 8 disk arrays to 16 disk array? What will be the rebuild times like for these configurations?

Note: RAID-10 is not an affordable option for this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a backup server, consider your space requirements as priority.

There's probably no need to make a RAID 60, unless there's a lot of data written in the same time. 2 arrays of RAID 6 should do fine, give you plenty of space and help reduce the time of a possible rebuild compared to having only one larger array. The one-large version will give you the extra space equivalent of 2 drive sizes.

As for the rebuild time, you can calculate the best-case rebuild rate fairly simple. As rebuild is sequential, the needed time is capacity / transfer rate. For example, rebuilding a 12 TB disk with a 240 MB/s transfer rate needs at least 10000000 / 200 = 50000s = ~14h.

Of course, there may be performance issues encountered along the way and you'll have to consider the average speed value across the drive, not the start speed rate.